# Find modulus of Z given that

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

if $Z = 1 + \cos 2\theta + i \sin 2\theta$

Find the modulus.
How will I begin solving? should I use de moivre's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately, you might observe that we are going to have some nice trig identites come into play...

$Z = 1 + \cos 2\theta + i \sin 2\theta = (1+\cos(2\theta))+(\sin(2\theta))i$

Simply use the definition of the modulus $\Rightarrow$

so $|Z|=\sqrt{(1+\cos2\theta)^2 +\sin^22\theta}=\sqrt{1+(\sin^22\theta+\cos^22\theta)+2\cos2\theta }=\displaystyle\sqrt{2(1+
cos2\theta) }=\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{2\cos^2\theta}=2|\cos\theta \ |$

**Reminder**: The modulus is always $\geq0$ as it is represents the distance from the complex number to the origin. And this occurs naturally from our working, yet a common mistake is to deduce that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$, so please take note!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1$$ and $$\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$$

and $|\cos A+i\sin A|=?$

Comment: Notice that $|\cos A|$ may not be equal to $\cos A$